# nuance of difference in etymology of "intend" and "attend"

Tags: preposition

I am trying to tease out the etymological difference between "intend" and "attend."  Both "in" or "en" as a Latin prefix and "ad" translate as "toward".  So the etymological sense of both words is "to stretch toward."  But we use the words *intend* and *attend* so differently in English that I am wondering if there is a nuance of difference in the root preposition.  Does anyone know?

Answer (score 3):

*In-* can indeed mean "in, into, towards". But *ad-* can mean "at" as well (in addition to "to, towards"). In fact, Germanic *at-* and Latin *ad-* are related via Proto-Indo-European.

Even so, the Latin verb *attendo* already had the meaning "to stretch or turn towards", so it was indeed the "to(wards)" sense used in this verb.

*Intendo* had a similar meaning. And both could be used with *animum*, "to direct one's attention to", and also without *animum*, with the same meaning. So I doubt whether you'll find the origin of the difference between the English verbs in their Latin praecursors.

Now, the English senses of both words are not so far removed from the general senses of their Latin forebears, so they aren't very surprising; but their praecise development is perhaps better traced in English, or in French, from which English took both words.

Comment: It's interesting that two words with such different meanings in my professional world (teaching artist) mean exactly the same thing at their root.  Strange journey of usage. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are two words in Latin from the Greek for stretch, τείνω. Dictionary **[Lewis&Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dattendo)** perseus

> *tendo (tenno ), tĕtendi, tentum and tensum*, 3, reach, stretch; Gr. τείνω.
>   *tĕnĕo , tĕnŭi, tentum,* 2 hold, grasp; Gr. τάνυμαι, τείνω

both words have enormous entries, and their meanings include::  tend, tense, tensile, put up a tent, tempt, (tentative), (tenterhooks). So, the range of meaning is already present in the simple verb.

Both intend and attend come from stretching a bow; aiming at a target. Attend is simply another way of showing close attention to your aim.

> ***in-tendo*** , di, tum and *-sum,* 3, v. a.
>   II C. Absol., to turn one's attention to, exert one's self for, to purpose, endeavor, intend:
>   II E. *Intendere animo,* **to purpose in one's mind,** to intend: “si C. Antonius, quod animo intenderat, perficere potuisset,” Cic. Phil. 10, 4, 9.—
>
> ***attendo*** (adt- , Dietsch), *tendi, tentum*, 3, v. a., orig.
>   1.to stretch something (e. g. the bow) toward something;
>   A. *Animum or animos attendere,* or absol. *attendere,* also *animo attendere,* to direct the attention, **apply the mind to something,** to 
>   attend to, consider, mind, give heed to (cf.: *advertere animum,* and *animadvertere;* freq. and class.)

The differences do not arrive even in French until 14th C.

> Old French atendre "to expect, wait for, pay attention" (12c., Modern French attendre)
>   Old French entendre, intendre "to direct one's attention" (from [Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/wor%20%20d/intend) "intend")

Comment: Two questions: 1) where are the quoted definitions from? 2) Why do you say the Latin words are "from" Greek? I would instead say that they are akin; they don't look like borrowings, and native Latin words are not thought to be derived from Greek, but from a common ancestor of both Latin and Greek that is thought to have been different from both.

Comment: @sumelic citations added.  τείνω is mentioned in the top line of L&S entries *tendo, teneo, & attendo.* and also in Ainsworth. Ainsworth gives a reduplicated Aorist *tetensi,* which hints at Greek. I've deleted 'from' -good idea

Comment: Yes, these two words seem indistinguishable at their root. The derivation of bow and arrow is helpful.  Thank you.